# Extract the 2nd columns from multiple tables and print them tab-delimited

Tags: sed, awk, multiple-columns, text-parsing

An input file contains several tables separated by `--`. Each table contains 3 columns. I want to take the 2nd column from each table and print the column values across tables tab-delimited.

input file:

```
402     52      2
403     68      0
404     0       0
405     0       0
407     1       3
--
1315    0       0
1316    0       0
1317    335     0
1318    2       3
1319    0       0
--
1892    0       0
1893    1       4
1894    0       0
1895    920     0
1896    2       3
```

output file:

```
52  0   0
68  0   1
0   335 0
0   2   920
1   0   2
```

Please suggest an `awk` or `sed` command. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following awk script:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk

BEGIN { nc=1; nr_ = 1; maxr = 1;}
/^--$/ {
    if (maxr < nr_ )
        maxr = nr_;
    nc++; nr_=1;
    next;
}
{ col[nc, nr_++] = $2; }
END {
    for(r = 1; r < maxr ; r++) {
        for(c = 1; c < nc - 1; c++) {
            printf("%s\t", col[c, r]);
        }
        printf("%s\n", col[nc-1, r]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for writing this program. It is working.

Comment: @FIROZ: If this answer solved your problem, please accept it by clicking the large check mark next to it. In addition, if other answers provided helpful as well, you can up-vote them.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way:

```
$ awk '
NF>1{++count; col[count]=(flag)?col[count] "\t" $2:$2; next}
{max=(max>count)?max:count; count=0; flag=1}
END{for(c=1;c<=max;c++) print col[c]}' file
52   0    0
68   0    1
0    335  0
0    2    920
1    0    2
```

Comment: +1; nicely done: both more concise and efficient; you're building up the output rows by collecting column values across tables row by row in a single-dimensional array (but more descriptive variable names would be nice :)

Answer (score 0):

Since data is repetitive you can do like this:

```
awk 'NR%6 {if (NR%6==1) f++;a[f FS NR%6]=$2} END {for (i=1;i<=6;i++) {for (j=1;j<=f;j++) printf "%s\t",a[j FS i];print ""}}' file
52      0       0
68      0       1
0       335     0
0       2       920
1       0       2
```

```
awk '
NR%6 {
    if (NR%6==1)
        f++
    a[f FS NR%6]=$2}
END {
    for (i=1;i<=6;i++) {
        for (j=1;j<=f;j++) printf "%s\t",a[j FS i]
        print ""}
    }' file
```